# ".DS" meaning in python

Tags: python-3.x

I know It's probably a very silly question, but could someone please tell me what's the meaning of ".DS" in the following function?? does it has a special python meaning or is it only used in this project and it's my bad that I didn't get it?

```
def load_paired_img_wrd(folder, word_vectors, use_word_vectors=True):

    class_names = [fold for fold in os.listdir(folder) if ".DS" not in fold]
    image_list = []
    labels_list = []
    paths_list = []
    for cl in class_names:
        splits = cl.split("_")
        if use_word_vectors:
            vectors = np.array([word_vectors[split] if split in word_vectors else np.zeros(shape=300) for split in splits])
            class_vector = np.mean(vectors, axis=0)
        subfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(folder + "/" + cl) if ".DS" not in f]

        for subf in subfiles:
            full_path = os.path.join(folder, cl, subf)
            img = image.load_img(full_path, target_size=(224, 224))
            x_raw = image.img_to_array(img)
            x_expand = np.expand_dims(x_raw, axis=0)
            x = preprocess_input(x_expand)
            image_list.append(x)
            if use_word_vectors:
                labels_list.append(class_vector)
            paths_list.append(full_path)
    img_data = np.array(image_list)
    img_data = np.rollaxis(img_data, 1, 0)
    img_data = img_data[0]

    return img_data, np.array(labels_list), paths_list
```

Comment: That bit of code is filtering out files with `.DS` in the name. The .DS has no special meaning in Python. It presumably has some significance for whatever the purpose of the code is.

Comment: I'm guessing it's trying to filter out the .DS_Store file that appears on macOS devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is probably trying to filter out the junk [`.DS_Store` files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store) that appear on macos

> The file .DS_Store is created in any directory (folder) accessed by the Finder application

Comment: That must be it, I'm a windows user so I didn't know about that, Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That's a text value.  It could as easily have been "BS" or "Foo!" and the code would operate in the same way.

In this case, the program is looking to see if there are files with the string ".DS" in them, and removing them from a list.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I was wondering why ".DS" in particular cause it doesn't have any thing to do with the project and folders name, I guess the above answer was the one